# CakePHP 3 Plugin development controller could not be found error

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to create an admin plugin for my website. I baked plugin then user model and controller but when I visit /admin/users/ or /admin/users/index it always gives an error as below:

> Error: Admin.UsersController could not be found.
>
> Error: Create the class UsersController below in file: C:\xampp\htdocs\cake3\plugins\Admin\src\Controller\UsersController.php

But of course I have the files in correct locations. Any ideas what causes this problem?

Thanks a lot for helps or even efforts.

Please ask any further info

Comment: did you create your plugin using bake?

Comment: yes Josê i created by shel using

cake bake plugin Admin

Comment: Show the code for your plugin controller and your composer.json file in your app. Use gist.github.com

Answer (score 13):

Add this line in config/bootstrap.php

```
Plugin::load('Admin', ['routes' => true, 'autoload' => true]);
```

Comment: Cakephp3 official documentation http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html 
says Plugin::load('Admin', ['routes' => true]); is enough. Wasted my 3 hours in checking error. adding 'autoload' => true worked !

Comment: Maybe this can help solve the issue : `php composer.phar update`

Comment: worked for me, but also continued to work after I removed the 'autoload' => true. Strange behaviour, somehow

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. It is about routes.php file in myplugin/config folder and composer.json in myplugin folder.

Jose the problem is not composer.json at the root location, i checked everything ok with the file. And i have code there as below.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src",
        "Admin\\": "./plugins/Admin/src"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Test\\": "tests",
        "Cake\\Test\\": "./vendor/cakephp/cakephp/tests",
        "Admin\\Test\\": "./plugins/Admin/tests"
    }
},
```

but i needed to make two more additions.

First created composer.json in my plugin folder.

```
{
    "name": "your-name-here/Admin",
    "description": "Admin plugin for CakePHP",
    "type": "cakephp-plugin",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4",
        "cakephp/cakephp": "3.0.x-dev"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Admin\\": "src"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Admin\\Test\\": "tests",
            "Cake\\Test\\": "./vendor/cakephp/cakephp/tests"
        }
    }
}
```

secondly I created routes.php file in "{mypluginfolder}/config" and added the codes below.

```
use Cake\Routing\Router;

Router::plugin('Admin', function ($routes) {
    $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
});
```

hope this help others

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there is a cached file in tmp folder:
myapp_cake_routes_route_collection

I deleted the file and the path worked.